# Prop.test with errors on the population proportions

Tags: r, chi-squared

I want to compare two population proportions with a chi-squared test but my population proportions come with error bars (e.g. [10,11] people in a population of [100,101]). I don't think that the function prop.test accommodates for that so I'm looking for another function that will do the job.

For instance, let's say that my populations are:

pop 1: [195, 198] people in a group of [215,218] people

pop 2: [101, 102] people in a group of [188,189]

I'm looking for a function that will calculate the chi-squared.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. But regardless it sounds more like a statistics question than a programming question. Thus it might be more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you please describe the chi-square test that you would like to conduct? Are you testing for equality of proportions between 2 populations? Could you provide your contingency table please?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this other than by Monte Carlo methods or brute-force integration ...

Comment: Your notation is kind of confusing especially coming rom an r context.   Could you write out your data creation in r?